# Listen multiple tcp ports with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

.--------.      .----------.      .----------.
| CLIENT | ---> | SERVER A |      | Cntrller |
'--------'      '----------'      '----------'
.--------.      .----------.      .----------.
| CLIENT | <--> | SERVER A | <--> | Cntrller |
'--------'      '----------'      '----------'
.--------.                        .----------.
| CLIENT | ---------------------> | Cntrller |
'--------'                        '----------'
.--------.                        .----------.
| CLIENT | <--------------------- | Cntrller |
'--------'                        '----------'

I want to listen to two TCP ports at the same time by using nodejs. One for Client the other one is Cntrller. First, the client sends an authentication request to the server. Then, the server broadcasts the client address with a random number to a specific port. After the client gets the random number, he/she sends it to the Cntrller with his/her own signature and his/her own public key. Then, the Cntrller checks the coming data from the client or not by verifying the coming public key and the random number.

But, I have to listen two different port and I couldn't do it by using TCP on nodejs. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Here is my code,

Server Part:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

// Get the filenames of user1 directory
dir_name = "../wallet/user1/";
const user1_info_dir = fs.readdirSync(dir_name);             

// Assign specific file names on them
const user1_pub_file = dir_name + user1_info_dir[1];

// Read .pem by using "pem-file" package
const user1_pub_pem = fs.readFileSync(user1_pub_file)


const net = require('net'); 
const host = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 9000;


const server = net.createServer(); 


server.listen(port, host, () => { 
    console.log(`TCP Client listening on ${host}:${port}`); 
}); 


let sockets = []; 
server.on('connection', (socket) => { 
    var clientAddress = `${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`; 
    console.log(`new client connected: ${clientAddress}`); 
    
    sockets.push(socket); 
    // console.log(sockets);
   
    socket.once('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`Client ${clientAddress}: ${data}`); 
        const crypto = require('crypto');
        const buf = crypto.randomBytes(256);
        //console.log(`${buf.length} bytes of random data: ${buf.toString('hex')}`);   
                
        //Write the data back to all the connected, the client will receive it as data from the server 
        sockets.forEach((sock) => { 
            var arr = [user1_pub_pem, buf];
            sock.write(Buffer.concat(arr));            
        }); 
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket 
    socket.on('close', (data) => { 
        let index = sockets.findIndex((o) => { 
            return o.remoteAddress === socket.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === socket.remotePort; 
        })

        if (index !== -1) sockets.splice(index, 1); 

        sockets.forEach((sock) => { 
            sock.write(`${clientAddress} disconnected\n`); 
        });

        console.log(`connection closed: ${clientAddress}`); 
    });

    // Add a 'error' event handler to this instance of socket 
    socket.on('error', (err) => { 
        console.log(`Error occurred in ${clientAddress}: ${err.message}`); 
    });
});
```

Client Part:

```js
var readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
var net = require("net");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 9000;

const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require('crypto');

dir_name = "../wallet/user1/";
const user1_info_dir = fs.readdirSync(dir_name);             // Get the filenames of user1 directory

const user1_priv_file = dir_name + user1_info_dir[0];        // Assign specific file names on them
const user1_pub_file = dir_name + user1_info_dir[1];
const user1_sig_file = dir_name + user1_info_dir[2];

const user1_priv_pem = fs.readFileSync(user1_priv_file)      // Read .pem by using "pem-file" package
const user1_pub_pem = fs.readFileSync(user1_pub_file)
const user1_sig_pem = fs.readFileSync(user1_sig_file)


var client = null;

function openConnection () { 
    if(client) {
        console.log("Connection is already open --");
        setTimeout(function (){
            menu();
        }, 0);
        return;
    }

    client = new net.Socket();
    
    client.on("error", function(err) {
        client.destroy();
        client = null;
        console.log("ERROR: Connection could not be opened. Msg : %s", err.message);
        setTimeout(function (){
            menu();
        }, 0); 
    });

    client.connect(port, host, function () {
        console.log("Connection opened succesfully");
        client.write("Hello my darling !");
   });

    client.on("data", function (data_from_sv) {
        console.log("Recieved: %s", data_from_sv);
        my_ip = client.address().address;
        var my_ip_buf = Buffer.from(my_ip, 'utf8');
        var durT = new Date();
        durT.setTime(1332403882588);        
        durT_str = durT.toString();
        duration_time = Buffer.from(durT_str, 'utf8');
        my_pub_key = user1_pub_pem;
        my_prv_key = user1_priv_pem;
        var arr = [data_from_sv, my_ip_buf, duration_time, my_pub_key];
        var new_data = Buffer.concat(arr);
        const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
        sign.write(new_data);
        sign.end();
        const signature = sign.sign(my_prv_key, 'hex');
        signature_buf = Buffer.from(signature, 'utf8');
        var arr2 = [signature_buf,my_pub_key];
        var whole_data = Buffer.concat(arr2);
        console.log(whole_data.length);
        client.write(whole_data);           
        // sendData(data_from_sv)

        setTimeout(function (){
            menu();
        }, 0); 
    });
}

function sendData(data) { 
    
}

function menu (){
    var lineRead = readlineSync.question("\n\nEnter option (1-Open, 2-Send, 3-Close, 4-Quit): ");

    switch(lineRead){
        case "1":
            openConnection();
            break;
        case "2":
            var data = readlineSync.question("Enter data to send: ");
            sendData(data);
            break;
        case "3":
            closeConnection();

            break;
        case "4":
            return;
            break;
        default:
            setTimeout(function (){
                menu();
            }, 0);
            break;
    
    }
}
 

setTimeout(function (){
    menu();
}, 0);
```

Controller Part:

```js
var readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
var net = require("net");
const crypto = require('crypto');
var bsplit = require('buffer-split')
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 9000;


client = new net.Socket();


client.on("error", function(err) {
    client.destroy();
    client = null;
    console.log("ERROR: Connection could not be opened. Msg : %s", err.message);
});

client.connect(port, host, function () {
    console.log("Connection opened succesfully");
});


// client.once("data", function (data_from_sv) {
//     sc_once_data = data_from_sv;
//     console.log("Recieved: %s", sc_once_data);
// });

client.on("data", function (data_from_sv) {
    console.log("Recieved: %s", data_from_sv);

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about creating two server objects?
Something like below:

```
const server1 = net.createServer(); 
const server2 = net.createServer(); 

server1.listen(9001, host, () => { 
    console.log(`TCP Client listening on ${host}:9001`); 
}); 
server2.listen(9002, host, () => { 
    console.log(`TCP Client listening on ${host}:9002`); 
});
```

This would listen on two different TCP ports i.e. 9001 and 9002. Or I completely didn't catch your question?

Answer (score 0):

I already tried this but  I couldn't handle data that comes from two clients for TCP communication. Then, I switched to UDP. I almost solved my question.

Here my UDP codes,

UDP Client:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
});
  
var my_public = publicKey;
var my_private = privateKey;

var udp = require('dgram');

var port = 5550;
var host = "0.0.0.0";

// creating a client socket
var client = udp.createSocket('udp4');

var data_cnt = 0;
var data;
var usr1_pub_pem;
var token;
var time = 100;
var sign_pub;

client.on('message',function(msg, info){
    //console.log('Received %d bytes from %s:%d\n',msg.length, info.address, info.port);
    console.log('Data received from server : ' + msg.toString());

    if(data_cnt == 1){
        data_cnt++;
        var token_tot = msg.toString().split(",")
        usr1_pub_pem = token_tot[0];
        token = token_tot[1];
        var message = token + "," + client.address().address + "," + time + "," + my_public;
        const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
        sign.update(message);
        sign.end();
        signature = sign.sign(my_private);
        sign_pub = signature.toString() + "," + my_public.toString();
        var sign_pub_buf = Buffer.from(sign_pub);
        console.log("sign_pub = ", sign_pub_buf);
        client.send(sign_pub_buf, port, host, function(error){
            if(error){
                client.close();
            }
            else{
                console.log('Sign+Public_K has been sent to server !!!');
            }
        });                
    }
    else if(data_cnt == 2){
        //sending msg
        client.send(msg, port, host, function(error){
            data_cnt ++;
            if(error){
                client.close();
            }
            else{
                console.log('New message has been sent to server !!!');
            }
        });            
    };  
});

if(data_cnt == 0){
    //buffer msg
    data = Buffer.from('This is client');
    client.send(data, port, host, function(error){
        data_cnt ++;   
        if(error){
            client.close();
        }
        else{
            console.log('Initial message has been sent to server !!!');
        }
    });    
}
```

UDP SDN:

```js
var udp = require('dgram');

var port = 5551;
var host = "0.0.0.0";

// creating a sdn socket
var sdn = udp.createSocket('udp4');

var data_cnt = 0;
var data;

var usr1_pub_pem;
var token;

sdn.on('message',function(msg, info){
    console.log('Received %d bytes from %s:%d\n',msg.length, info.address, info.port);
    console.log("data_cnt = ", data_cnt);
    if(data_cnt == 1){
        console.log('Data received from server : ' + msg.toString());
        //console.log("data_cnt = ", data_cnt);
        var token_tot = msg.toString().split(",");
        usr1_pub_pem = token_tot[0];
        token = token_tot[1];
        data_cnt++;
        console.log("data_cnt = ", data_cnt);
    }
    else if (data_cnt == 2){
        console.log('Data received from server : ' + msg.toString());
        data_cnt ++; 
        var sig_pub = msg.toString().split(",");
        var pub = sig_pub[0];
        var sig = sig_pub[1];
        //...
        //...
    }

});

if(data_cnt == 0){
    //buffer msg
    data = Buffer.from('This is SDN');
    sdn.send(data, port, host, function(error){
        data_cnt ++;   
        if(error){
            sdn.close();
        }
        else{
            console.log('Initial message has been sent to server !!!');
        }
    });    
}
```

UDP Server :

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////     START        //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const fs = require("fs");

// Get the filenames of user1 directory
dir_name = "../wallet/user1/";
const user1_info_dir = fs.readdirSync(dir_name);             

// Assign specific file names on them
const user1_pub_file = dir_name + user1_info_dir[1];

// Read .pem by using "pem-file" package
const user1_pub_pem = fs.readFileSync(user1_pub_file)

var dgram = require('dgram');
const host = "0.0.0.0";

var udp_cli_port = 5550;
var address_cli;
var cli_port;
var cli_family;
var cli_ipaddr;

var udp_sdn_port = 5551;
var address_sdn;
var sdn_port;
var sdn_family;
var sdn_ipaddr;

const crypto = require('crypto');
var rand_buf = crypto.randomBytes(256);
var rand_str = user1_pub_pem.toString() + "," + rand_buf.toString();


var count_cli = 0;
var count_sdn = 0;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////      CLI PART        //////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var udpsocket_cli = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
udpsocket_cli.bind(udp_cli_port,host);

udpsocket_cli.on('listening', function() {
    address_cli = udpsocket_cli.address();
    cli_port= address_cli.port;
    cli_family = address_cli.family;
    cli_ipaddr = address_cli.address;
    console.log("listening "+cli_ipaddr+" port::"+cli_port);
});

udpsocket_cli.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
    //console.log('Data received from client : ' + msg.toString());
    //console.log('Received %d bytes from %s:%d\n',msg.length, rinfo.address, rinfo.port);    
    //console.log("message received :: "+ msg +" address:: "+rinfo.address+ " port = "+ rinfo.port );
    //sending msg
    if(count_cli == 0){
        udpsocket_cli.send(rand_str, rinfo.port, host, function(error){
            count_cli ++;
            if(error) {
                udpsocket_cli.close();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Random number has been sent to CLIENT !!!');
            }
        });        
    }
    else if (count_cli == 1){
        console.log('Data received from client : ' + msg);
        udpsocket_cli.send(msg, sdn_port, sdn_ipaddr, function(error){
            console.log("sdn_port = ", sdn_port);
            console.log("sdn_ipaddr = ", sdn_ipaddr);
            count_cli ++;
            if(error) {
                udpsocket_cli.close();
            }
            else {
                console.log('CLI --------> SDN');
            }
        });        
    }
});

// emits when any error occurs
udpsocket_cli.on('error',function(error){
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
    udpsocket_cli.close();
});

//emits after the udpsocket_cli is closed using udpsocket_cli.close();
udpsocket_cli.on('close',function(){
    console.log('udpsocket_cli is closed !');
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////      SDN PART        //////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var udpsocket_sdn = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
udpsocket_sdn.bind(udp_sdn_port,host);

udpsocket_sdn.on('listening', function() {
    address_sdn = udpsocket_sdn.address();
    sdn_port= address_sdn.port;
    sdn_family = address_sdn.family;
    sdn_ipaddr = address_sdn.address;
    console.log("listening "+sdn_ipaddr+" port::"+sdn_port);    
});

udpsocket_sdn.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
    //console.log('Data received from client : ' + msg.toString());
    //console.log('Received %d bytes from %s:%d\n',msg.length, rinfo.address, rinfo.port);    
    //console.log("message received :: "+ msg +" address:: "+rinfo.address+ " port = "+ rinfo.port );
    //sending msg
    if(count_sdn == 0){
        udpsocket_sdn.send(rand_str, rinfo.port, host, function(error){
            count_sdn ++;
            if(error) { 
                udpsocket_sdn.close();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Random number has been sent to SDN!!!');
            }
        });        
    };       
});

// emits when any error occurs
udpsocket_sdn.on('error',function(error){
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
    udpsocket_sdn.close();
});

//emits after the udpsocket_sdn is closed using udpsocket_sdn.close();
udpsocket_sdn.on('close',function(){
    console.log('udpsocket_sdn is closed !');
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////     END        ////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```